# What is the point of free standing blocks if there is no block scope?

Tags: javascript, syntax, lexical-scope

> You are allowed to use free-standing blocks like this...

```
var something = 1;
{
  var something = 2;
  print("Inside: " + something);
}
print("Outside: " + something);
```

This is from: http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html#p3c7ae609

But what's the point of having blocks like that? What purpose does it serve?

Comment: Ooops, I kept reading, and: _"In fact, although blocks like this are allowed, they are utterly pointless."_ Guess I'll vote to delete the question?

Comment: Might as well. It is not something we could answer anyway and is certainly under the "not constructive" umbrella.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In ES6 there'll be block scoped variables declared with `let`, at which free-standing blocks won't be pointless any more.

Comment: Also see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12646143/1597180

Answer (score 3):

Free standing blocks don't usually add any value in a script, however they *can* be used for code organization, such as splitting out an equation:

<sub>One Line:</sub>

```
//long equations are hard to read
foo = bar * baz + fizz - buzz;
```

<sub>Block:</sub>

```
{
    //this groups relevant information into a descrete section
    foo = bar;
    foo *= baz;
    foo += fizz;
    foo -= buzz;
}
```

Although, long equations that perform operations based on a standard set of inputs are usually broken out into their own function:

<sub>As Function:</sub>

```
function qux(bar, baz, fizz, buzz) {
    var ret;
    ret = bar;
    ret *= baz;
    ret += fizz;
    ret -= buzz;
    return ret;
}

foo = qux(bar, baz, fizz, buzz);
```

Comment: Accepted this but check out @Alnitak's as well.

Comment: odd, I'd never consider using a block the way you did in your example because the braces add nothing useful.  It would be just as well done with four separate lines with some whitespace (and maybe a comment) separating it from the preceding code.

Comment: @Alnitak yeah, that makes sense, though I hadn't thought of it that way. Visual masturbation?

Answer (score 1):

Ooops, I kept reading, and here's my answer:

> In fact, although blocks like this are allowed, they are utterly pointless.

http://eloquentjavascript.net/chapter3.html#p6f53387f

Answer (score 0):

You answered your own question. From the article linked in the OP:

> In fact, although blocks like this are allowed, they are utterly
>   pointless.